# Handle image and delta updates using protobuf 3

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

Having this proto message :

```
message Price
{
Double bid = 1;
Double ask = 2;
Double last = 3;
Double tick = 4;
Int64 bidQty = 5;
Int64 askQty = 6;
String tradingPhase = 7;
// ... other fields
}
```

Is there an efficient way to handle delta updates.

After sending the full image (whole message) the first time, I need to send/receive only modified fields. Using proto 2, there is `has_field()` method for each field to check the existence of a field in the message.

Is there a solution using the proto 3 without defining all fields as optional ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the relevant [documentation](https://protobuf.dev/programming-guides/proto3/#specifying-rules)

> Message fields can be one of the following:
>
> - singular: a well-formed message can have zero or one of this field (but not more than one). When using proto3 syntax, this is the default
>   field rule when no other field rules are specified for a given field.
>   You cannot determine whether it was parsed from the wire. It will be
>   serialized to the wire unless it is the default value. For more on
>   this subject, see Field Presence.
> - optional: the same as singular, except that you can check to see if the value was explicitly set. An optional field is in one of two
>   possible states: the field is set, and contains a value that was
>   explicitly set or parsed from the wire. It will be serialized to the
>   wire. the field is unset, and will return the default value. It will
>   not be  serialized to the wire.
> - repeated: this field type can be repeated zero or more times in a well-formed message. The order of the repeated values will be
>   preserved. map: this is a paired key/value field type. See Maps for
>   more on this field type.

It sounds like you need to declare the fields optional in order to test whether they are specified.

Comment: proto2's field presence got removed from proto3, but was recently put back in due to user demand https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/docs/implementing_proto3_presence.md

Comment: I'm using the 3.19 version and got always the error has_xxx unkown !

Answer (score 0):

I have found three approaches for handling updates with protobuf.

1. Using the optional keyword for all fields:
   This approach involves marking all fields in the protobuf schema as optional. When updating an existing protobuf message, only the fields that are explicitly set in the update request will be modified. This approach requires more careful handling of fields that are not set, as the default values may not be what is expected.
2. Using protobuf MaskField:
   The MaskField approach involves sending an update request that includes a protobuf message containing a mask field that indicates which fields in the original message should be updated. The server then applies the update by only modifying the fields that are specified in the mask. This approach is more efficient than the first approach, as it allows for partial updates, and avoids sending unnecessary data over the network.
3. Using protobuf wrappers:
   The third approach involves wrapping all fields in the protobuf schema with a "wrapper" message that contains the primitive type

```
message DoubleValue {
  // The double value.
  double value = 1;
}
```

Then protoc will generate the has_xxx() method to test if the field is set or not.